# Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webMetric

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Error when starting Spring project with Java 8

POM:

```
<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>Camden.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <start-class>br.com.medwise.library.ms.MedLibraryMS</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
    <metrics-spring.version>3.1.2</metrics-spring.version>
    <liquibase-slf4j.version>1.2.1</liquibase-slf4j.version>
    <usertype-core.version>5.0.0.GA</usertype-core.version>
    <liquibase-hibernate4.version>3.5</liquibase-hibernate4.version>
    <hikaricp.version>2.4.1</hikaricp.version>
    <assertj-core.version>2.1.0</assertj-core.version>
    <docker.image.prefix>medwise</docker.image.prefix>
    <docker.image.name>library</docker.image.name>
    <liquibase.version>3.4.2</liquibase.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/br.com.caelum.stella/caelum-stella-bean-validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.caelum.stella</groupId>
        <artifactId>caelum-stella-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--AWS-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot and Test Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <!-- parent POM declares this dependency in default (compile) scope -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Swagger API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson Datatype -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate for Audit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>${usertype-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- liquibase integration database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mattbertolini</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase-slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Check the POM dependencies, I analyzed the classes in the domain and repository package without success.

error stack:

```
C:\Users\brunocris\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_362\jre\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:52288,suspend=y,server=n -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:C:\Users\brunocris\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar=file:/C:/Users/brunocris/AppData/Local/Temp/capture7.props -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\brunocris\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath1220475643.jar br.com.medwise.library.ms.MedLibraryMS
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52288', transport: 'socket'
2023-09-29 15:13:35.329  INFO 1220 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@22bf9122: startup date [Fri Sep 29 15:13:35 BRT 2023]; root of context hierarchy
2023-09-29 15:13:35.543  INFO 1220 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : 
                                                                `---'
 
Powered by Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE
2023-09-29 15:13:37.305  INFO 1220 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2023-09-29 15:13:39.416  WARN 1220 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/server/default": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2023-09-29 15:13:39.417  INFO 1220 --- [           main] br.com.medwise.library.ms.MedLibraryMS   : The following profiles are active: false
2023-09-29 15:13:39.427  INFO 1220 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@539316bb: startup date [Fri Sep 29 15:13:39 BRT 2023]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@22bf9122
2023-09-29 15:13:42.369  INFO 1220 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'restTemplate' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=restClientConfiguration; factoryMethodName=restTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [br/com/medwise/library/ms/config/RestClientConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=restTemplateConfig; factoryMethodName=restTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [br/com/medwise/library/ms/config/RestTemplateConfig.class]]
2023-09-29 15:13:42.374  INFO 1220 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'restTemplate' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=restTemplateConfig; factoryMethodName=restTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [br/com/medwise/library/ms/config/RestTemplateConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=restService; factoryMethodName=restTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [br/com/medwise/library/ms/service/RestService.class]]
2023-09-29 15:13:42.375  INFO 1220 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'messageSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=localeConfiguration; factoryMethodName=messageSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [br/com/medwise/library/ms/locale/LocaleConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=medLibraryMS; factoryMethodName=messageSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in br.com.medwise.library.ms.MedLibraryMS]
2023-09-29 15:13:42.449  INFO 1220 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]]
2023-09-29 15:13:42.638  INFO 1220 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'managementServletContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]
2023-09-29 15:13:42.746  WARN 1220 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2023-09-29 15:13:42.849  INFO 1220 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=32688575-b02f-3162-9c69-e613be320155
2023-09-29 15:13:43.145  INFO 1220 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.export.StringToDurationConverter' of type [class io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.export.StringToDurationConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-29 15:13:43.150  INFO 1220 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'libraryms-br.com.medwise.library.ms.properties.LibraryProperties' of type [class br.com.medwise.library.ms.properties.LibraryProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-29 15:13:43.151  INFO 1220 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'asyncConfiguration' of type [class br.com.medwise.library.ms.config.AsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4fa1bf4b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-29 15:13:43.161  INFO 1220 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 
2023-09-29 15:13:43.162  INFO 1220 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'taskExecutor' of type [class br.com.medwise.library.ms.exception.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-29 15:13:43.306  INFO 1220 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e0d128c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-29 15:13:43.530  INFO 1220 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a271589] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-29 15:13:43.898  INFO 1220 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-09-29 15:13:43.905  INFO 1220 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2023-09-29 15:13:43.905  INFO 1220 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2023-09-29 15:13:43.953  INFO 1220 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/med-library-api/v1]      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-29 15:13:43.953  INFO 1220 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4526 ms
2023-09-29 15:13:45.546  INFO 1220 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/med-library-api/v1]      : jolokia: No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
2023-09-29 15:13:47.035  INFO 1220 --- [ost-startStop-1] liquibase                                : Successfully acquired change log lock
2023-09-29 15:13:48.294  INFO 1220 --- [ost-startStop-1] liquibase                                : Reading from public.databasechangelog
2023-09-29 15:13:48.306  INFO 1220 --- [ost-startStop-1] liquibase                                : Successfully released change log lock
2023-09-29 15:13:48.587  INFO 1220 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-09-29 15:13:48.603  INFO 1220 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
```

Comment: The log doesn't appear to show the error in the question's title

Comment: The error is `Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/server/default": Connection refused:`.  What's supposed to be listening on port 8888?